# How to Get a part of URL and put in shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, urls

I have this shortcode

```
[broo_user_badges username=""]
```

and I have to put username between " "
But, username is in URL: /author/peter.
So, when page domain.com/author/peter was loaded, on that page this shortcode should be generated:

```
[broo_user_badges username="peter"]
```

I found this

```
add_shortcode('name', 'get_name');
function get_name() {
   return $_GET['name'];
}
```

here [How to get URL param to shortcode?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155588/how-to-get-url-param-to-shortcode)
but I do not understand how to use that on my case (/author/peter url structure).

Edit: plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/badgearoo/

Comment: Please edit your question mentioning the shortcode plugin you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function get_name() {
    $url = "http://domain.com/author/peter";

    if (preg_match("/author/", $url )) {
        $lastSlash = strrpos( $url, "/");
        return substr( $url, $lastSlash, strlen($url));
    }
}
```

This will return everything after the last slash.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to get author name from url

> 1. Using [get_query_var()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/)

```
// http://example.com/author/peter
$author_name = get_query_var('author_name'); // peter
```

> 2. Using [get_queried_object()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/)

```
// http://example.com/author/peter
$author_info = get_queried_object();
$author_name = $author_info->user_login; // peter

// print_r($author_info); // to see more information about Author
```

For more information read [Custom Author Information](https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Custom_Author_Information)